# Iphone: Calling a function in a view controller from the super view controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, interface-builder

Hi Im new to Iphone App development. I have a Tab bar based application. In one of the Tabs I have a Custom Navigation View controller with a Custom Table View Controller. How do I call a function in the Custom Table View Controller from the viewDidLoad method of the Super Controller i.e the Custom Navigation View Controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you instantiating the Custom Table View Controller? Is it a Nib or programmatically.

If the former use an IBOutlet from the Custom Navigation View Controller to the instance of the custom TV controller.

If the latter just keep a ivar handle to the custom TV controller when you create it.

as in `self.ctvc = [[[MyCVTV alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];`

where ctvc is `@property (readwrite,retain) MyCTVC *ctvc;`

Dont forget to release in the dealloc overide

```
-(void)dealloc {
self.ctvc = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

So when you wish to use the method from the `viewDidLoad` method. `[ctvc doSomething:thing]`

But UINavigationController isnt designed for sub-classing . 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You should rethink your object structure

Comment: I think I didn't put my question across properly. Let me try again I have a tab bar based app. I have set 5 tabs in the mainview.xib from IB. One of the tab is of type Navigation Controller inside it is a Table View Controller I want to call a function that I have defined in TV controller when the Navigation view loads up. I am guessing the Navigation View controller loads up before the TV controller. How do I do this? Sorry if I haven't been clear and sorry about the poor English.

Comment: You cant. Until you have instantiated the TV controller you cant use it . However bear in mind that you can instantiate the view controller and not present it.

Comment: Actually thats not strictly true. You could define a class method of the TV Controller. So you can use it without instantiating.